# python chunksize difference

Tags: python, pandas, chunks

I have a question regarding reading large csv file with chunksize.
My question is: what is the difference between these two below?

```
import pandas as pd
chunks = pd.read_csv("large_data.csv", chunksize=1000000)
chunk_list = []  

# Each chunk is in dataframe format
for data_chunk in chunks:  
    filtered_chunk = chunk_filtering(data_chunk)
    chunk_list.append(filtered_chunk)
    
final = pd.concat(chunk_list)
```

```
chunks = pd.read_csv("large_data.csv", chunksize=1000000)
final = pd.concat(chunks)
```

Is there any performance difference?

Comment: Did you test it? Both are fundamentally different because one is filtered, the other is not. Filtering can remove 99% of all data ....

Comment: Why read in chunks íf you will add them into one pd anyway - is there any benefit to do that memorywise? doubt it somehow - but it is just a hunch.

Comment: @PatrickArtner I can import it directly but I'm just curious on why others advised using `chunksize`.

Comment: If you have a 10GB CSV file and a PC with 8GB ram  you can not fill all the data inside your ram. Using chunksize avoids that - if you end up trying to load ALL into your ram using chunksize without any filtering on the data - you'll end up with the same problem as with not using it : _it does not fit_.  However if you filter your data and say, only 1GB of the 10GB file are left after filtering, using chunks will make it go smoother as you only hold those data items in your dataframe that are important (less then 1GB) plus an additional 1 Megabyte chunk of raw csv data to be filtered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have doubts regarding efficiency, as @Patrick Artner suggested, just test it :

```py
start = time.perf_counter()
final = pd.read_csv("large_data.csv")
print(time.perf_counter() - start)
```

```py
start = time.perf_counter()
final = pd.concat(pd.read_csv("large_data.csv", chunksize=1_000_000))
print(time.perf_counter() - start)
```

Or if you're using Jupyter :

```py
%%timeit
final = pd.read_csv("large_data.csv")
```

But the answer to your question is : using chunksize and concat will be clearly slower than the direct usage.

chunksize is useful only if you treat your data like you're doing with your filter.

The idea is to avoid your computer memory to be overloaded by any mean.

Here again, make the test it : if you have 16 Gb of memory, create a **str** by reafecting up to the moment your memory is full. As soon as you get there your computer performances will drop drastically !

So we deal with chunks small enough to make the treatments within computer memory limits...

Under Jupyter :

```py
a = 'a'*1_000_000_000
```

Run the following cell while looking at your memory usage :

```py
a += 'a'*1_000_000_000
```

And see by yourself... :)